# Can I setup WordPress in a subdirectory and then point my URL to the subdirectory when I'm ready to go live?

Tags: migration

I have a client that has a current WordPress installation in their website root, and they are creating a new WordPress site which is in a subdirectory during development. My question is, what do I do when they are ready to go live and replace their current WordPress install with the new dev version? Can they just point their main URL to the subdirectory instead of having to move the entire dev site into the root of their website? Will this work with WordPress?

Comment: Do you want to keep the subdirectory in the URL? Or does it still have to appear as if the site is at the top level domain (www.domain.com)

Comment: I would like it to appear so that the site is at the top level domain if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress allows for this setup, and they have complete instructions here:

[Giving WordPress its Own Directory While Leaving Your Blog in the Root Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

I personally would move the files because to me it's cleaner, but the above mentioned solution should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I had read that already. The whole reason I'm asking this is because I am not going to be available the day the client wants to go live, so they asked if they could just use the redirect method I mentioned above which does not require any coding changes or file moves. If I follow that article, I might as well just move the whole site. I'm basically just looking for an easy way to go from dev to live without having to do any coding changes or file moves. I'd love it if someone could just answer "you can't do that", which I could relay to the client :)

Comment: This solution works great except for some themes that modify the htaccess file heavily.

Comment: I have tried that and it works well, but home url is not working well it gets wordpress url. I am using also polylang. Can you advise me for a solution ?